# Exporting color ramp as gradient to Illustrator/Indesign?

Tags: qgis-3, export, color-ramp, illustrator

How do I export a gradient from QGIS to Illustrator and/ or indesign?
I know I can export a gradient on a layout, but is there also a way to export the gradient in a file format that illustrator can read as native gradient swatch?

Comment: How do you use said gradient? What do you plan on doing with it in illustrator?

Comment: please add some more context... What have you tried?

Comment: I have updated the main question: is there a way to export a said gradient so that I can use it as swatch in illustrator? In Illustrator you can load in predefined gradients (and also save custom made ones), can QGIS export them to .ai or .ase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, copy the gradient from the styles manager and follow along this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTwrKCH5Qd8

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I made a screenshot from the styles manager with the said colour ramp, then uploaded it to adobe's colouring website (https://color.adobe.com/nl/create/image-gradient) and manually made the gradient from the HEX colours, for some reason you cannot download the a custom gradient or use it from the creative cloud libraries.